# What is the name of the type of sentence that's formatted like "performing an action"?

Tags: grammar

So I am sure the title of this question makes little sense, but I don't know how to ask it (feel free to edit it to make it more direct, but not so direct that it answers the question).

There is a certain sentence format that's used mainly in movie titles that's not really a complete sentence, but more along the lines of a clause of sorts.  You've seen movie titles like:

> Being John Malkovich
>   Forgetting Sarah Marshall
>   Driving Miss Daisy
>   Gleaming the Cube (good one, right?)

It seems to me that this fragment of a sentence has a name or is at least identifiable in some way.

Edit:  The only tag I can think of is `grammar`, so feel free to add additional tags.

Comment: Haha, wow!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund.  I think you should post that as answer and get tons of upvotes.

Answer (score 11):

When an *-ing* verb acts as a noun, it is traditionally called a *gerund*. It’s still a non-finite verb, and so can take complements:

> Hitting kids on the playground will get you kicked out of school.
>
> Being yourself is the most important thing you can do.
>
> That’s not for shooting squirrels with, sonny.

Comment: Right. These are Gerund phrases, which are Verb phrases with the verb in the _-ing_ form. They have a subject, but it's not stated here, and who the subject is is a legitimate concern with titles like this. Who is the person who's sposta be John Malkovich, forget Sarah Marshall, or drive Miss Daisy? The fourth one is ungrammatical, however, since _gleam_ isn't causative and can't take an object.